# Why is select id slower than select * in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

### Background

We're using mysql 5.6 and encounter a serious slow query online.

The table can be simplified to

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `job_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `job_id` (`job_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name   | varchar(20)  | NO   |     |         |                |
| job_id | bigint       | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

There are 1M rows and all job_id is ZERO.

We create `job_id` index named `job_id`.

`eq_range_index_dive_limit` is 10

### Problem

When we select with sentence:
`select * from user force index(job_id) where job_id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11);`
it cost (0.01 sec)

```
explain select * from user force index(job_id) where job_id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: user
   partitions: NULL
         type: range
possible_keys: job_id
          key: job_id
      key_len: 8
          ref: NULL
         rows: 10979573
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
```

but when we select with sentence:
`select id from user force index(job_id) where job_id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)`
it cost (0.27 sec)

```
explain select id from user force index(job_id) where job_id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: user
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: job_id
          key: job_id
      key_len: 8
          ref: NULL
         rows: 998143
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
```

```
mysql> show index from USER \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        Table: user
   Non_unique: 0
     Key_name: PRIMARY
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 913536
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null:
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
      Visible: YES
   Expression: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
        Table: user
   Non_unique: 1
     Key_name: job_id
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: job_id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 1
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null:
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment:
Index_comment:
      Visible: YES
   Expression: NULL
```

We used `optimizer trace` and we found `best_covering_index_scan` happened in the second SQL. And optimizer chosen scan table.

Why the first SQL didn't chose scan table?
Why `select id` is much slower than `select *`, and `select name` is as fast as `select *`?

Comment: Did you reset and flush query cache before each test?

Comment: Test your query on a million of records and you can see `select id` is faster than `select *`. your current size is not enough to see the impact of optimization.

Comment: Thanks for your replies and we add a lot more info. We did select in million rows while select * is still much faster.

Comment: Is your comparison conclusive? Can you restart your mysql and rerun? If the second sql is executed after the 1st sql, buffer pool could play a role, i.e., mysql has load the data when executing 1st sql.

Comment: Hi Jacob, these sql works the same no matter how many time you run it, and we also test it on Mysql 5.7 and 8.0 and performance still the same

Comment: Your statistics may be wrong, e.g. do you really have only one distinct value in `job_id`? If not, can you run `analyze table user` and try again? If this doesn't fix the execution time, can you compare the total times (e.g. duration + fetch time), as disregarding the fetch time might be misleading here.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for the two cases.